# How to prevent the rerenders and improve performance (Todo example with hooks)

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-hooks

I want to dig into React hooks a little bit and have been trying to figure out how to make my components more performant. Even though I think I'm using `useCallback` at the right place, my application feels really slow, because too many updates happen.

What could I improve so only one or two components change instead of recreating the whole thing?

```
function createTodos(number) {
  const todos = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    todos.push({
      id: i,
      toggled: !(i % 4)
    });
  }
  return todos;
}

function Todos() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(() => createTodos(10000));

  const toggleTodo = useCallback(
    id => {
      setTodos(
        todos.map(todo => {
          return todo.id === id ? { ...todo, toggled: !todo.toggled } : todo;
        })
      );
    },
    [todos]
  );

  return useMemo(
    () =>
      todos.map(todo => (
        <Todo
          key={todo.id}
          todoId={todo.id}
          toggled={todo.toggled}
          toggleTodo={toggleTodo}
        />
      )),
    [todos, toggleTodo]
  );
}

function Todo({ todoId, toggled, toggleTodo }) {
  const toggle = useCallback(() => toggleTodo(todoId), [todoId, toggleTodo]);
  return useMemo(() => {
    const style = {
      background: toggled ? "green" : "red",
      margin: 2,
      padding: 4
    };
    return (
      <div style={style} onClick={toggle}>
        {todoId}
      </div>
    );
  }, [todoId, toggled, toggle]);
}
```

Example (open with caution as I'm rendering 10k components): https://codesandbox.io/embed/quizzical-sun-92qnw

To compare performance with a useReducer solution:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-hodgkin-gdo2g

The reducer solution is a lot faster (because of course the reducer reference never changes, BUT I am using useCallback on all function I )pass as a callback so shouldn't I have the same result with the 1st example?

Comment: The 10K components in your example take a second or two to load on my (reasonably fast) machine, but after that it works fine. What makes you think too many updates are happening? Try manually changing the background of component 13 to blue, with your browser's code inspector. If then you go and toggle a different component, the one you changed should still be blue - i.e., only the one you clicked re-rendered.

Comment: Well it's quite slow to change one Todo from toggled to non toggled and vice versa. Like if you  got like 100 Todos, you can just just rapidly toggle it. But with 10k items one toggle takes like 200ms. Which is 5FPS.

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by instead of declaring my `toggleTodo` function like:

```
const toggleTodo = useCallback(
    id => {
      setTodos(
        todos.map(todo => {
          return todo.id === id ? { ...todo, toggled: !todo.toggled } : todo;
        })
      );
    },
    [todos]
  );
```

In this case the todos are dependancies, and anytime the todos are changing, this gonna receive a new reference, and everything gonna be re-rendered as our shallow reference gonna be different.

So the solution:

```
const toggleTodo = useCallback(
    id => {
      setTodos(oldTodos => 
        oldTodos.map(todo => {
          return todo.id === id ? { ...todo, toggled: !todo.toggled } : todo;
        })
      );
    },
    []
  );
```

our useState 2nd parameter can be either a value or a function callback. By using the function callback the todos no longer gonna be dependancies and we gonna be able to avoid these re-renders (actually these aren't re-renders, but recalculations?)